# Logo shows old URL with HTTPS protocol

Tags: magento2, configuration, https, logo

On my development store, I changed the URL recently which made the **logo disappear**. The image link keeps showing the old URL unless I use unsafe URL's in the frontend in

> stores > configuration > general > web

That seems like strange behavior to me.

Why does this old URL persist in https and how to get rid of it?

Comment: please check web/unsecure/base_media_url and web/secure/base_media_url

Answer (score 1):

Open your database and search your old url. You have to change in this table :

> core_config_data

Now you can see two **path** like this one is `web/unsecure/base_url` and second is `web/secure/base_url`.  Please replace its **value** to your new url.

After this, flush your caches and storage. This will solve your problem.

Edit: You can saw it in given screenshot. [image]